# Read multiple csv's and concat to multiple dataframes based on filenames python

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a list of csv's with the same columns. Here is how the list looks like,

```
C:/Users/foo/bar/January01.csv
C:/Users/foo/bar/February01.csv
C:/Users/foo/bar/March01.csv
C:/Users/foo/bar/January02.csv
C:/Users/foo/bar/March02.csv
```

I want something like this, all csv's that start with January should copy the data into January dataframe and likewise for all months.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can first iterate trough your directory to find all months you have, then you pass again appending the dataframes and finally saves them:

```
import os
dir_name = #your dir
months = set()
for file in os.listdir(dir_name):
    months.add(file[:-2])

month_df = {month: pd.DataFrame() for month in months}
for file in os.listdir(dir_name):
    month_df[file[:-2]] = month[file[:-2]].append(pd.read_csv(os.join.path(dir_name, file)))

for month in month_df.keys():
    month_df[month].to_csv(month + '.csv', index=False)
```